# Почему элементы массива numpy не добавляются? python

Tags: python, numpy

У меня не добавляются элементы в массив numpy. colors - это массив, созданный с помощью zeros((7, 16)). Когда я вывожу u, то у меня u не имеет значение ноль(то есть он заполняется), а когда я вывожу массив у меня он по нулям. Как это решить? Часть кода:

```
colors = np.zeros((7, 16))
lists = []
# здесь был какой-то код...
r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(lists))
for u in np.nditer(colors):
    num_of_iters += 1
    if num_of_iters == 1:
        u = r
        num_of_iter = 0
        print(u)
        lists.clear()
```

Comment: Если что я знаю что я немного туповат :0

Comment: Вам нужно понять, что переменная u отвязана от colors. Если вы хотите изменять элемент листа, обращайтесь к нему по индексу.

Comment: u не имеет обратной связи с colors, вы туда в явном виде должны значения присваивать

Comment: Все, я понял спасибо

Comment: Вы бы лучше описали более широко то, что вы пытаетесь сделать - скорее всего этого можно добиться векторизированным способом. Т.е. код будет выглядеть элегантнее и работать на порядок быстрее ;)

Comment: Не помешало бы:) А не понимаю, что значит :'векторизированным способом'. Я туповат. Я же говорил:0